# How to unmarshal a xml file without translating masked special characters?

Tags: java, xml, special-characters, unmarshalling

A field in a xml file is filled with "`O&#039;Neill`", which translates to "O'Neill". But due to law restrictions we are not allowed to alter the given information, so we have to supress this translation.
Right now we are using JAXB to unmarshal the file. But as soon this is done, the given object has the translated O'Neill. We failed to find a way to forbid the unmarshaller to translate.

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz.getPackage().getName());
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(xmlFile, Charset.forName(codepage));
    Object result = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

I found several hints for the CharacterEscapeHandler, but that only seems to work for a marshaller, not for an explicit unmarshaller. 
The charset is needed, since we are obliged to check for the right encoding.
The reader alone doesn't do anything. We checked and "`O&#039;Neill`" was read out of the file.
The Codepage of the XML is Codepage is ISO-8859-15.
The critical line is definitiv the last one. The reader reads it correctly, after the unmarshalling the value is translated. (Seen it in the debugger).

If anyone knows a way to get the un-altered "`O&#039;Neill`" in an object, either with JAXB or another way, every hint is appreciated.
(We are using XSD schemes to unmarshal into an object.)

Comment: O'Neill is the value of the attribut or its name ?

Comment: the value of the attribute

Comment: Oh, and the problem is right here.. O & # 0 3 9 ; Neill, the sequence was translated in my post, I changed it

Comment: There are 4 lines in your code. Have you identified whether the last line or 3rd lines makes the issue (translation) ?

Comment: Also what is `codepage` ASCII or UTF-8 or any other ? And what is the encoding given in your XML file ?

Comment: Encode it for XML escape back in setter.

Comment: Problematic line: Object result = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
The reader has read it perfectly fine, the object has it wrong.
Codepage is ISO-8859-15

Comment: And what is the encoding given in your XML file ?

Comment: Codepage is ISO-8859-15 - Please update your question with these details

Comment: @smilyface: did it, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

`O'Neil` is legally correct: `from-xml(to-xml("O'Neil")) == "O'Neil"`.

When `"O'Neil"` was put into the XML it was converted to `"O&#39;Neil"` as an apostrophe is a special character in XML.

ASCII 39 is the apostrophe `'` so it is not as if a zero 0 was altered into a capital O. I would even say that the form with `&#039;` corrupts the original `O'Neil`.

I you still need to do it:

As several forms for those entities are possible: `&apos; &#39; &#x27;`, a re-escaping like `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML(...)` will not do too.

You'll need to intercept the entity handling, and translate to the original text as-is.

For discussion, argumenting. Note that the encoding of the XML, say UTF-8 influences the bytes. If those contain an accented letter like `é` a conversion to some Windows encoding should also result in a readable é, not two weird chars (the latter not converting those bytes for é).

Comment: could you please quote the "O& #039;Neill"? First sentence makes as much sence as mine before I noticed, that the site is translating it. ^^ Well, I will check the interception then...

Comment: With that pseudo-equation I just wanted to express that O'Neil goes into the XML, stored as whatever, and comes out of the XML as O'Neil.